# Is it a good practice to reuse a CollectionViewController or is it preferable to create another one?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I just want to reduce code duplication by creating only one `UICollectionViewController` instead of two because they will be almost the same. I just need to give the user an perception of a transaction like adding a `BackButton` and doing a Transaction Effect like when performing a segue to another view in a `NavigationController`.

To add some context:

I'm building an App that is a Viewer for a remote FileSystem where contains files and folders. When the user opens a folder I just want to refresh the screen, "do the transaction effect" and "unhide" the back button to act like a navigation. My `CollectionViewController` is already inside a Nav.

--

Usually I build this behavior with two different files with almost the same code.. it seems soo wrong to me.

Comment: You're exactly on the right track. You should eliminate code duplication wherever possible. You can transition between 2 instances of the same `CollectionViewController` class.

Comment: when click on the folder, how about just change the `datasource` of your collectionViewController

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Alexander's comments that using 2 instances of the same `UICollectionViewController` would be a reasonable way to go.

If there are differences between the 2 you could create a base class with the common attributes and then subclass that base class with the unique features you need for reach.